# Assigning values in one vector to indices in another vector?

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework

Basically I have been trying to assign a new vector with values from another.This can be done sequentially using :

```
vDSP_vindex(A,B,Stride,C,Stride,Length)
```

So if A has 10 elements,B has 20 indices and C has 20 elements; we assign all the values in C using the elements in A at indices defined in B.

But what if I want to have the indices of C in B? to be populated with elements from A.

Hope someone can help with this.

Comment: What if you just change A,B and C accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He wants C[B[i]] = a[i] rather than C[i] = a[B[i]].   The problem with this construction is that there is no guarantee that all the elements in C are defined, or what happens when two indices in B are the same -- which one ends up in C?

Assuming these problems don't bother you, you need to transform the elements in B[i] to be the right values for the other formulation. This is just a matter of:

```
initialize Bprime[] to a default value for undefined.
for each i in [0,N)
    Bprime[B[i]] = i;
vDSP_vindex(A,Bprime,Stride,C,Stride,N)
```

Whether this is worth it or not probably depends entirely on whether Bprime can be reused.